# Spark - Not able to read a .csv file with Multiple lines record to a dataframe

Tags: csv, apache-spark

I am trying to read a .csv with multiline records to a Spark data frame. My .csv looks like below. The first line is a header.

```
Software,Version,Date,Update Date,Extended Support,Reference,Notes
Windows,Windows XP,12/28/2022,12/28/2023,12/28/2024,https://www.software.com/,"Some notes"
VxWorks,VxWorks ,,,12/28/2024,https://www.software.com/,"Some Notes

with multiple lines"
```

I am using the below code to read the above file.

```
val df = spark.read
      .option("header", true)
      .option("sep", ",")
      .option("inferSchema", false)
      .option("multiLine", true)
      .option("escape","\"")
      .csv(s"${file_path}")
```

This one is considering all row values as columns. Not sure where it's going wrong.

```
scala> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- Software: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Version: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Update Date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Extended Support: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Reference: string (nullable = true)
Windows: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Windows XP: string (nullable = true)
 |-- 12/28/2022: string (nullable = true)
 |-- 12/28/2023: string (nullable = true)
 |-- 12/28/2024: string (nullable = true)
 |-- https://www.software.com/: string (nullable = true)
 |-- "Some notes
VxWorks: string (nullable = true)
 |-- VxWorks: string (nullable = true)
 |-- <blank>: string (nullable = true)
 |-- <blank>: string (nullable = true)
 |-- 12/28/2024: string (nullable = true)
 |-- https://www.software.com/: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: What version are you on? Your code works fine for me on Spark 3.0.1

Comment: @CharlieFlowers My spark version is 2.4